# Create JWT access token from a SAMLAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt, spring-saml

In my application I have so far used the OAuth2 password grant flow to generate a JWT access token to clients providing their username and password using Spring Security and Spring OAuth. They then use that token in all requests to my Spring Boot REST API.

Some of my customers now want to use SAML authentication instead. My idea is to create a separate endpoint `/saml/accessToken` and secure it with Spring SAML. Once the SAML authentication is complete the user is redirected back to `/saml/accessToken`, now with a valid authentication, and is given a JWT which the client can use to further communicate with my REST API.

I need a controller method that accepts an authenticated SAMLAuthenticationToken, generates a JWT using it's credentials, and returns it to the client:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saml/accessToken")
public String getAccessToken(SAMLAuthenticationToken authentication) {
    return accessTokenFactory.create(authentication);
}
```

It is the `accessTokenFactory` in the above example I need help with. I would like to follow the Spring coding ecosystem as much as possible and avoid using a "hack" solution, so that I can make use of the already existing TokenEnhancers and so forth.

---

**What is the best way to create a JWT access token from a SAMLAuthenticationToken?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, the `Authentication` object for the SAML cookie resulting from a successful SAML authentication flow is actually an `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`, not a `SAMLAuthenticationToken`. The `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken#principal` is the `User` implementation (lets call it `CustomerUser`) I set during the SAML authentication in my `SAMLUserDetailsService` implementation, which is the same type of `User` that I use in the OAuth2 password grant flow.

Since I didn't find any way of using the default Spring OAuth way of creating a JWT for the `ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken`, I ended up writing a separate `JwtFactory#create(ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken)` using `jjwt`. This lead to a clean and easy solution.

The main drawback of doing it this way is that the `JwtFactory` cannot make use of my `TokenEnhancer` beans, that are responsible for adding additional parameters to the JWT. Therefore there exists som level of code and logic duplication for adding additional JWT parameters, both in the `TokenEnhancer`s (used by Spring OAuth) and the `JwtFactory` (used manually after SAML authentication). This is a code smell that should be avoided. But hacking Spring OAuth specific functionality into my custom `JwtFactory` seems even worse, so this is something I'll have to live with.

Comment: Could you share some details of your implementation? Specifically how you handled the token creation and redirect and how you receive the token on the client. Is the request to /saml/accessToken user initiated or a request by some kind of HTTP library?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried below code and it's works for me.

After successful SAML (Okta) Login user redirect to below method which we have configured in SAML Configuration Class

```
  @Bean
@Qualifier("saml")
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {
    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/oauth/saml/token");
    return successRedirectHandler;
}
```

---

```
 @RequestMapping("/oauth/saml/token")
    public String home(ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken userToken) throws JsonProcessingException {
        SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) userToken.getCredentials();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("group", credential.getAttributeAsStringArray("group"));
        Assertion authenticationAssertion = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion();
        String access_token = getSamlJWTToken(authenticationAssertion, map);
        map.put("access_token", access_token);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String token = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);
        return token;
    }

private String getSamlJWTToken(Assertion authenticationAssertion, Map<String, Object> map) {
        String SECRET_KEY = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(samlKeystorePassword.getBytes());
        String id = authenticationAssertion.getID();
        String issuer = authenticationAssertion.getIssuer().getValue();
        String subject = authenticationAssertion.getSubject().getNameID().getValue();
        DateTime notBefore = authenticationAssertion.getConditions().getNotBefore();
        DateTime notOnOrAfter = authenticationAssertion.getConditions().getNotOnOrAfter();
        SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;
        byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SECRET_KEY);
        Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());
        JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(map)
                .setId(id)
                .setIssuedAt(notBefore.toDate())
                .setSubject(subject)
                .setIssuer(issuer)
                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey)
                .setExpiration(notOnOrAfter.toDate());
        return builder.compact();
    }
```